# What are all the chord qualities?

Tags: theory, harmony

I am working on some chord sorting algorithms right now, I was requested to add an algorithm that is capable to sort chords by chord quality, so afaik there are only major, minor, diminished, or augmented chords.

But what happens for example suspended chords?? , they can't be neither major nor minor, so should I have all of the chords that do not are maj, min, dim or aug in a separate pile?, or are there more chords qualities?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: There are more. This web page is good.  https://www.edmprod.com/different-chord-types/

Comment: Are you limited to three notes per chord?

Comment: Ask the requester to provide a list of such "qualities". If they used such a word, then most certainly they can explain what they meant by it? What is the intended purpose of this chord classification? What kind of a person (or another algorithm?) should be able to do what, by utilizing this sorted order? What do you get as input - textual chord names, or note combinations?

Comment: @rlo Great page.  Do you know if it's possible to play Ext. 9th and Ext 11th chords on a guitar?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I would Google that question and look through the many web pages with that content.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's walkthrough of a calculation of the highest number of chord qualities that you could consider qualities (more on that later). **Mathematically, there are a bunch of combinations of intervals that produce chords.** There are 12 notes available for the 1st note in the chord, then 11 for the 2nd, then 10, etc. A note any multiple of 12 semitones (an octave) above or below another is the same note and doesn't change chord quality.

12! chord qualities.

However, note that this number is the number of chords that take all 12 chromatic notes. To find all the chords with any number of notes from 1 to 12 inclusive, we need to add in the number of chords with fewer notes. However, once you have that number, you must be careful of enharmonicity. Basically, that's like looking at every note, then considering each note the root, and checking for duplicates. Also, some combinations of intervals form an inversion of another different chord. That's the reason why there's only one chord quality for a 12 note chord (which makes sense, when you think about it).

**So, in reality, here's what I can get from intuition** (I'm not great at math).

- 1 12 note chord (like we said)
- 1 11 note chord (all 12 notes minus one note at any interval to the 1st, but reordering all of them makes them all the same)
- 1 one note chord (but don't count that, generally a note is not a chord)
- 11 two note chords (any note plus any other)
- 110 3 note chords (any note plus any of 11 others plus any of 10 others)

With lots of notes, checking that none of the notes can be considered the root of a different chord quality is extremely difficult. But mathematically, there are hundreds at least. Let me also note that **depending on how you limit your horizons of chord qualities, the number of notes is extremely variable. If you consider only diatonic triads to major scales, there are only 3 qualities.**

Comment: Inversions also drop the number of unique chord qualities substantially.

Comment: Also there are 55 (not 110) unique 3 note chords before accounting for inversions- choosing root M3 and P5 is the same as choosing root P5 and M3.  We could probably account for all 3 note chord "qualities" with a reasonable number of combinations- but is it useful to classify "root m2 M2" as a chord?  Is that in root position?

Comment: Does this answer the question? I thought it was asking for a list of all chord qualities [in Western music], not a number of possible chord qualities that exist. The question seems to imply that it's focused on Western music given the examples that appear up above (maj, min, dim, aug).

Answer (score 1):

There are 4096 possible combinations of 12 pitch classes.  These form 352 distinct chord qualities.

Of these 352, there are 19 triads:

- the four we know well
  maj, min, aug, dim...
- Some we know less well
  sus, b5,
- A bunch we know as other chords with notes missing
  7(no 5), min7(no 5), maj7(no 5), 69(no 3, no 5), maj7(no 3),
  min7(no 3), -7b5(no 3)..
- and the fragments we don’t usually think of as chords
  chromatic (012), Viannese triads (017 & 067), split 3/6 (034 & 014), and do re mi (024).

Each of these has 12 transpositions that yield distinct combinations of pitch classes except augmented which has only four.

Comment: There are other combinations with less than 12 transpositions: dim7, tritone diad, whole-tone scale cluster, 12-tone chromatic cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated question as, as someone else stated I think, it depends on the definition of quality. Sure when you are learning in a quite traditional way in the UK and only talking triads then the main 'types' (I'm going to avoid the word 'qualities' due to the ambiguity ;) ) you are told about are major, minor, dim and aug. But as you mention wanting to include sus chords too, what about all the other chords out there?

One of the most powerful and common movements in all of music is the V I, and although it's not always used the fact that the V is a dominant7 is key to the movement in a lot of cases. It's the only 7th chord of it's type in a major tonality, hence it's called dominant, so I would surely be thinking that it's an important one to consider!

As all the 7 chords in the major scale are either Major7, Minor7, Dom7 or Minor7b5 I would say theres good argument to include all of those, as they are the main building blocks for the majority of western tradition composition, even if you don't PLAY the 7th of each chord theres always a RIGHT one hanging there in potentia, if you are playing diatonically. But then, what about the fully diminished? The synthetic one? Including the minor7b5 from the major scale means our diminished triad we referenced earlier is now used up as 'that' sound. So I would include HalfWhole / WholeHalf diminished as well, as that is (despite the similar name) a whole other unrelated area of theory compared to the diatonic minor7b5.

And how about MinMaj7? Thats a VERY particular sound that doesn't come from major scale tonality, but harmonic and melodic minor tonality (that it DOES belong to) are hundreds of years old and definitely a part of the deep foundation of western harmonic tradition. The MinMaj7 chord sounds like nothing else on the list so far so that would definitely be included for me!

I'm a jazz musician + a theory nerd, as such I really could go on for pages and bore everyone to sleep as then we get into the character of lydian chords, minor6's, lydian dominant chords, altered, susb9 (easter egg for jazz theory nerds ;) ), b9 or #9 dominants, b13 dominants, major7#5, some of the inversions of all the above etc etc. Each of these are generally non substituteable (well, ok, EVERYTHING is substitutable creatively but I mean in terms of 'type of chord' ;) ) for a given threshold of 'quality type'.

And in this, I'm trying to come from the direction of describe the functional chords, starting from the triads and working up. as others have said, if you come from the other direction realistically there are so many thousands of options to be incomprehensible to visualise. Though I would imagine a lot of those would functionally work as each other and the true number of distinct qualities would settle somewhere around 'a lot'.

So, I think you need to make a choice of where you narrow your parameters, I'm not sure what the scope of your project is, but I would certainly include the 7's (maj7, min7, dom7, min7b5 (half-dim) and possibly MinMaj7), I'd group Maj6 with Maj7, and perhaps put the majority of dominant type chords with dom7 (altered, lydian dominant, dare I say H/W dim? or MAYBE whole tone?) But as you can see I'm questioning that even as I type :D. Then I'd save a space for sus, augmented, harmonic minor (super locrian) diminished, min6, W/HDim (I mean it's a mode of the H/W dim that I grouped in with Dom7, but it's quite different and non transferrable if you are extending the chord with available intervals...)..

Anyway, I hope I have made my argument by confusing myself! It would take me a while to get MY list, and there are tonnes of niche but specific chords types I'm thinking of at the moment that I haven't even mentioned, hopefully it's food for thought!